# Status of default initialisation of struct fields?

Tags: julia, language-lawyer

Under Julia v0.6, the simple code:

```
julia> struct A
             x::Int = 1
       end
```

generates this error:

```
ERROR: syntax: "x::Int=1" inside type definition is reserved
```

This is quite an elusive message: reserved for what?

-> Do I have to understand that this kind of definition is going to be allowed in future Julia revisions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is available via [Parameters.jl](https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl).

```
julia> using Parameters

julia> @with_kw struct A
           a::Int = 6
           b::Float64 = -1.1
           c::UInt8
       end

julia> A(c=4)
A
  a: 6
  b: -1.1
  c: 4
```

Comment: Thanks. However, under the hood the macro still transforms this into  an usual constructor `A(a,b,c) = new(6,-1.1,c)`. I was thinking of a construct natively supported by Julia with the hope that It could open the door for further optimizations of the generated code.

Comment: In a later version of Julia this is planned. It just [moved to a 1.x milestone](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10146) because anyone that wants it now can use Parameters.jl, so it's not a big reason to hold back Julia 1.0.

Comment: It won't open up more optimizations. Julia 1.0's keyword argument and literal inlining + interprocedural optimizations will optimize this completely.